# Connecting to a python socket behind a router

Tags: apache-2.2, router, port-forwarding, socket

I have a Python script on my server which opens a socket that can be connected to from anywhere.
It works on my digitalocean test server that has a public IP as shown by ifconfig.
It does not work on my work server which is behind a router and perhaps a firewall (ifconfig shows a private IP)

Do I need to mess with the router settings and allow port forwarding?

I have installed apache as my understanding is that it's needed to do anything with web (like sockets), although I am not hosting any webpages or browser based stuff, just the socket.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options for allowing external access to your server with private IP:

1. Forwarding a port from the router/firewall, which protects this server. How to do it depends on the type of the router/firewall.
2. Using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to circumvent the firewall.
3. Build yourself VPN connection into the server's LAN - again on the router/firewall. Again, depends on the type of the router/firewall.
4. Run some king of proxy on the router/firewall, which proxies the incoming connections to the internal IP of your server. Which proxy depends on the protocol you are running, for HTTP i suggest [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/).

Depends on what do you need to achieve.

If you want permanent, worldwide access to the service you are running, i suggest number 1 or 4.

If you want to just do some temporary tests, number 2 or 3.